# Calculate ping time android

Tags: java, android, latency

How to calculate latency/ping time in ms for an ip address from android.

I want to implement this in my app.
I have tried the following code but it does not output anything

```
private void executeCommand() throws IOException {
    String pingResult="  ";

    Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p=r.exec(new String[] {"ping", "-c 4", "www.google.com"});
    try {
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Going loop", 1).show();
    while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null)
    {
        pingResult+=inputLine;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pingResult, 1).show();
    System.out.println(pingResult);
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used adb shell ping [Click](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-ping).

adb have no ping. 
adb shell have no ping

Or [netstat](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-shell-netstat)